# Earliest 2Q on board

Tags: opening, records, material

```
[FEN ""] 
1. d4 d5 2. Bf4 Nf6 3. e3 c5 4. dxc5 e6 5. b4 a5 6. c3 axb4 7. cxb4 b6 8. Bxb8 Rxb8 9. Qa4+ Ke7 10. c6 b5 11. Qa7+ Ke8 12. c7 Bxb4+ 13. Kd1 1-0
```

Let's not analyze this horror too much...If I had played Black, I had played 13...Qd6 14.cxb8Q O-O!!! and only THEN resigned :-)

But which is the game with the earliest occurrence of two queens of the same color? [Krabbe](https://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/records/records.htm) answers "QQ-QQ" but is there a faster QQ-Q or so?

Comment: Most likely a game that two people played long before there were tournaments

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch I suppose "earliest occurence" here doesn't mean "earliest game" but "game where the queen promotion happened after the fewest moves"...

Comment: @Evargalo: Indeed. Since the 4Q record takes 7 moves and you need 5 to promote alone, it would be hard to beat.

Comment: must be a really bad game for it to happen lol

Comment: Krabbé doesn't seem to quite answer this question.  Probably you can find a game where somebody misplayed the "Lasker Trap" and went 7 . . . fxg1Q? (briefly gaining a second Queen, but allowing 8 Qxd8+ Kxd8 9 Rxg1) instead of 7 . . . fxg1N+!

Comment: or even 1 e4 Nf6 2 Nc3 d5 3 e5 d4 4 exf6 dxc3 5 fxg7 cxb2?? 6 gxh8Q bxa1Q 7 Qxa1 1-0

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: I tried on LiChess, but only 1 White (2200! - those who don't know history are doomed to repeat it) fell into it and no Black took a queen. Probably someone with a Megabase has to check.

Comment: my megadatabase 19 only shows 19 games with albin counter all played fg1N. and 0 games with the alekhine

Comment: @HaukeReddmann, it would be faster in Bughouse (but as @cmgchess said, it would be a bad game). As I'm not sure about Bughouse notation, here's a Crazyhouse game that's similar: `1. d4 e5 2. Bg5 exd4 3. Bxd8 Kxd8 4. Q@g5+`. And in normal chess, why not something like `1. f4 f5 2. e4 fxe4 3. f5 e6 4. f6 c6 5. f7+ Ke7 6. fxg8=Q` (yes, the moves are bad)?

Comment: I assume the queen is supposed to stay (i.e. that games where the queen is captured the move after the promotion should be excluded).

Comment: @double-beep, does the queen stay in my Bughouse/Crazyhouse versions?

Comment: @HaukeReddmann to clarify: are you looking for a real (OTB) game?

Comment: @double-beep: Indeed, no constructed one. That would take just 5 moves - to promote. (And preferrably no patzers, my opponent was over 2000.)